# Removing short-cycles in LDPC codes

Tags: coding-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of removal of short cycles(i.e. 4-cycles, 6-cycles, etc) in LDPC codes. Can someone elaborate on this concept and possibly provide an example?

Comment: Basically it means that the Tanner graph of the resulting code should not have these cycles. The Tanner graph describes the connections between bits and check equations. So a 4-cycle is something like: bit1-check1-bit2-check2-bit1. In other words, a pair of bits participating in two check equations. In the parity check matrix it means that there will be two columns and two rows such that there are ones on all four intersections.

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense. So with relation to my previous question, how would I best estimate how many 1s i need in each row. For instance, if I have (128, 64), how do I know how many 1s I want in a column and how many I want in a row? My understanding so far is that I can choose any odd number, between 1-10 reasonably, of 1s for each column. For instance five 1s in each column and ten 1s in each row.

Comment: I don't know how to select a good the column weight distribution. That is the key part of LDPC code design I am unfamiliar with. A process called density evolution will help in finding good distributions. The math is over my head, you can try and study Urbanke's book. Or, you can try some small numbers, and see  how well the code works. Different weight distributions lead to different locations of the waterfall.